# How to resolve IndexError: index (x) is out of bounds for axis 0 with size (y) in wxPython?

Tags: python, animation, wxpython

Here I am trying to display animation of jawline. Running the code gives an error on calling OnClicked() event.

```
def OnClicked(self, e):
    print("ok")
    self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure_animation, self.animate , init_func=self.init, interval=0.1,
                                       blit=True)

def init(self):  # only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
    x = self.mat_px[0]
    y = self.mat_py[0]
    self.jaw_outline.set_data(x, y)
    return self.img, self.jaw_outline

def animate(self, i):
    # update the data
    x = self.mat_px[i]
    y = self.mat_py[i]
    self.jaw_outline.set_data(x, y)
    poa = self.axes_animation.scatter(self.h2_POA_pos[i], self.K2_POA_pos[i], color='red', s=150)
    jaw_area_fill = self.axes_animation.fill_between(x, y, 0, facecolor=[(254 / 255, 157 / 255, 111 / 255)])

    return self.img, self.jaw_outline, jaw_area_fill, poa
```

Consider if the length of self.mat_px is 80, then I get this "index 80 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 80 " error continuously in pycharm console. I get non stop errors like below.

- IndexError: index 80 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 75.
- IndexError: index 81 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 75.
- IndexError: index 82 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 75.
- so on

And if I set blit as False then i don't get any error but doing that does not give me the proper result.
Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the `%` (modulo) operator (see [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)), to limit the index to the range of `self.mat_px` respectively `self.mat_py`:

```py
x = self.mat_px[i % len(self.mat_px)]
y = self.mat_py[i % len(self.mat_py)]
```